# TLS Handshake Steps

Tags: ssl, handshake

I know basic steps of a TLS Handshake but I don't have knowledge about detailed verification steps of certificates during TLS. My question is at below;

Let us assume that our system supports OCSP/CRLs verification. In this case, is the first step to verify incoming certificate using CRLs or OCSP Responder? Or look for the incoming certificate is in TrustStore or not, at first?

Thanks four your help

Comment: It depends. TLS doesn't define that. It's up to the implementation. Too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably not find a definitive document on that, in part because people have shifted away from these 2 methods of revocation check (they are disabled by default in some browsers or when enabled do not produce very useful UI)

Nowadays people prefer OCSP Stapling (see https://casecurity.org/2013/02/14/certificate-revocation-and-ocsp-stapling/ for some reasons) over CRLs or OCSP.

But to go back precisely to your question, since both CRLs and OCSP typically mean going to fetch something remotely, this needs network access and can create delays. So if you have a local TrustStore with all the certificates you should first check that, before having to do a remote call.

Also the CABForum Baseline Requirements (at https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-certificate-contents/) specify that CRLs endpoints MAY be present in a certificate but OCSP endpoint MUST be present, except if you are doing OCSP Stapling instead.
On top of that EV certificates mandate OCSP.

So, in short it may make sense to do things in this order:

1. Check in local TrustStore
2. Do an OCSP query
3. Download a CRL

Note that nowadays you have also other options:

- DANE, hence checking DNS TLSA records
- Certificate Transparency Logs
- oneCRL / CRLset